# Creating domain with thousands of values for ArcGIS feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-collector, domains

I am creating a feature class for the ArcGIS Collector App and want to create domain table for an attribute field.  The problem is that I have 6335 possible values that could be used for the field.  Is it possible to create this table externally and then import into domain table?

Comment: That many values will make Collector unusable. Strongly suggest you rethink your strategy, may be ArcPad may be a better solution where you could build an interface that can deal with that number of options.

Comment: Maybe using subtypes would make the domains smaller. see also https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/a-quick-revisit-subtypes-and-domains-in-collector-for-arcgis/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you may want to rethink your schema if you have that many values for a single domain, there are tools available in ArcGIS to help you do this. One thing I am not sure of is if there is a limit in ArcGIS to how many domain values the gdb can store for a single domain.

The workflow would be to create your values in a gdb table, dtable or excel, then use the the tool "Table to Domain" (under Data Management) in ArcGIS.